# Is there something similar to tf.cond but for vector predicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Say I have a 5D tensor `x` and a 1D boolean mask `m` where `m.shape[0] == x.shape[0]`, and I want to decide which sub-network should be applied on each 4D sample inside `x` based on the corresponding boolean entry of `m`.

To my knowledge `tf.cond` accepts scalar predicator only. Though `tf.boolean_mask` may be helpful to split the samples inside a batch into two subsets according to `m` as desired, I am not sure how to re-pack the outputs back into one 5D tensor without messing up the original sample order. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to evaluate the data on both models and the use `tf.where` to select the final output.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def model1(x):
    return 2 * x

def model2(x):
    return -3 * x

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None])  # 2D for simplicity
    m = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, [None])
    y1 = model1(x)
    y2 = model2(x)
    y = tf.where(m, y1, y2)
    print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], m: [True, False, True]}))
    # [[  2.   4.]
    #  [ -9. -12.]
    #  [ 10.  12.]]
```

If you really want to avoid that, you can use `tf.boolean_mask` to split the data and then recombine it with `tf.scatter_nd`. This is one possible way.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def model1(x):
    return 2 * x

def model2(x):
    return -3 * x

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None])
    m = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, [None])
    n = tf.size(m)
    i = tf.range(n)
    x1 = tf.boolean_mask(x, m)
    i1 = tf.boolean_mask(i, m)
    y1 = model1(x1)
    m_neg = ~m
    x2 = tf.boolean_mask(x, m_neg)
    i2 = tf.boolean_mask(i, m_neg)
    y2 = model2(x2)
    y = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(tf.concat([i1, i2], axis=0), 1),
                      tf.concat([y1, y2], axis=0),
                      tf.concat([[n], tf.shape(y1)[1:]], axis=0))
    print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], m: [True, False, True]}))
    # [[  2.   4.]
    #  [ -9. -12.]
    #  [ 10.  12.]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently I overlooked the sentence "...`condition` must be either a vector with size matching the first dimension of `x`, or..." in the [documentation of `tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where); and good to know [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd).